# How can I test the responsiveness of my non-hosted website on my phone?

Tags: website-design, mobile, responsive-design, front-end-development, mobile-first

I wonder if there is a similar tool to *[Skala Preview](http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/)* (it is for live preview of photoshop work on your iPhone via Wifi) to test my web design (**`index.html` and its assets folder**) onto mobile phones (iPhone, Android and WinPhone). I need to check that *viewport*, *mediaqueries* and other design questions are working as expected...

I already use *[Resizer](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/)* but it is not to test directly on mobile devices, I don't want an emulator. I have tried *Dropbox* and *Drive*, but that last one doesn't work on mobiles and both are so tricky of use. I am not a developer and I don't understand the most of those strange languages beyond HTML and CSS... But I can't believe there's no an easy way to do what I am asking for. It shouldn't be so difficult!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Probably https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gotomypc-remote-desktop/id417742726?mt=8  or any other software that helps to connect to you PC, navigate through files and run them with installed applications (safari for example)

Comment: Yes, I know I should have a hosting account. I've learned everything by my own and I don't know how to configure a hosting. It scares me... but I'll try it. I was hoping there was an easier solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can get any free hosting solution. All you need is FTP access and it will works like a distant folder. Nothing scary )

Comment: Thank you all. Vnovak, Scott, I know it looks easy for people who have already used it, but I just want to feel myself understood. I don't know what is a FTP, a web server or anything else like that, because I am a designer. I know photoshop, sketch, illustrator, HTML, CSS, jQuery, color psychology, and much more, but not these things. I think I need to put a developer on my life... any volunteers? XDDD

Comment: Candy, if you're creating markup (HTML/CSS) for the web professionally, and worried about responsiveness and browser testing, there's no avoiding the *basic* information about FTP (File Transfer Protocol) and moving files to a hosting account so you can test them. Most "developers" will roll their eyes if you ask them to handle this exceptionally basic step. The "as a designer" comment isn't doing you any good. :) **All** web designers I know can handle these steps.

Comment: I am not trying to avoid this responsability. Quite the contrary. I know that I have to improve my productivity and to be more independent. I have learned lots of things which actually not have any relation with design. And I am very proud of that. But I have done that because I wanted to do it, not because I had to do it. My question asked for some **alternate** and more easy way of test, nothing else. Not asked for the standard way. I've said I'll do it and I've done it. Thanks one more time. But it wasn't my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try GhostLab...it's awesome but also Premium. It allows you to test your designs live on every device with no need of Hosting, just with your local machine and internet connection.

Comment: I've tried it, it's what I was looking for... thank you!

Comment: @CandyKillah Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5):

Most web designers or developers have their own web site which has hosting. You can simply create a subfolder on your hosting account and drop the web site into that... and access it via `http://www.yourdomain.com/subfolder`. If you don't have a hosting account, get one. They run as little as $40 a *year*.

Other options include using things such as [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/), [LAMP](http://linuxsolutions.org.in/lamp.html), or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to create a local server environment.

All you really need is a web server running on your local network. Some operating Systems already have a preinstalled server environment. The [MacOS](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) has Apache built in (I don't know about Windows). With that, all you need is the Local IP of the system running the server.

Comment: I'll need help of some developer to do all that, but thank you very much.

Comment: You probably don't need the help of any developer. Purchasing and setting up a hosting account is pretty easy. There's nothing to be scared about.

Comment: FYI, Windows has IIS inbuilt, but you need to turn this feature on to host webpages.

Comment: Another option would be to let your computer host it you should be able to connect to the ip directly. For convenience you could use some of the free dynamic name services so you dobt need to look up the ip.

Comment: I've tried [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) and it covers my needs too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Adobe Creative Cloud, you can view live previews of your website on any kind of mainstream mobile device using [Edge Code](http://html.adobe.com/edge/code/) and [Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/). Changes happen as you edit in Edge Code, so you can get instant feedback on how different devices will handle changes to the HTML and CSS without having to continually push changes up to a server via FTP.

Answer (score -1):

you can test your website online on any kind of device with different resolutions as well as your own required resolution.
[Mobitest.comli](http://mobitest.comli.com)